# Python get/set value of dict of dicts by key in variable

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding, getter-setter

I have dict of dicts in Python, it can be deep, not just 2 levels.

```
data = {
    0: {
        1: {
            2: "Yes"
        },
        3: {
            4: "No"
        }
    },
}
```

I need to get and set the data, but the key is dynamic and is stored in list

```
key_to_get = [0,1,2]

print(data.get(key_to_get))
```

Should print `Yes`

Ideas?

Comment: use recursion .

Comment: You can use something like `reduce` or you use a easier to understand loop... `value = data; for k in key_to_get: value = value[k]`...

Comment: Sure I can do recursion but maybe there is some standard way, or funny way, or built in type that can do that?

Comment: @HardQuestions there isn't.

Comment: just use a for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive function which solves the problem

```
def getValue(dict, keys):
    if len(keys) == 1:
        return dict.get(keys[0])
    return getValue(dict.get(keys[0]), keys[1:])
```

And an iterative approach if you're boring

```
temp = data
for key in key_to_get:
    temp = temp.get(key)
print(temp)
```

Comment: @JonClements yeah I realize it is tail recursion but its just one possible solution

Comment: I prefer the boring approach :) Also - not quite sure how useful `.get` is here... if the key didn't exist to start with you're going to get `None` which just means things are going to fail on any further iterations because `None.get` won't work... probably best to just use `temp[key]` and let the `KeyError` raise on that one instead of an `AttributeError` on the next.

Comment: That's all is boring ;) sorry, also I need to set values as well.

Comment: @HardQuestions then you get the nesting by looping over everything except the last key wanted, then do `temp[last_key] = some_value`...

Comment: Iteration should be preferred in Python over recursion. Function call overhead is much larger than the overhead of a for-loop.